Will FFmpeg continue encoding, converting when sleep mode?
Will it run? I was curious so I could make a 24 hour video. It doesn't even matter what my space is, but is it possible?
For example I take my live video and put FFmpeg, then I will leave it overnight.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Applications generally don't work in sleep mode. As the name suggests, everything is "sleeping" = in a state where they don't do anything.
If you want to ensure that your machine doesn't go to sleep without tinkering Windows power plans and settings, e.g. if you aren't certain that ffmpeg or any other app will prevent that, you can use a simple application like Awake that sends signals to the system that stop it from sleeping. You can enable/disable this state from e.g. tray icon.

FFmpeg will not run in sleep mode. But if it is already running the computer won't enter sleep mode from the start. I would be more worried about Windows Automatic Updates than computer entering sleep mode. Besides you can turn off sleep mode in the power management.
